# SQL query to only select row if specific condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
friends.name as friendname,
friends.surname as friendsurname,
friends.number as friendnumber,
friends.gender as friendgender, 
clients.name as clientname,
clients.surname as clientsurname
FROM friends
INNER JOIN clients
ON friends.clientid = clients.id
WHERE datetime(friends.creationdate, 'localtime') >= datetime('SOME_TEST_TIME') AND datetime(friends.creationdate, 'localtime') <= datetime('SOME_TEST_TIME')
```

Both the `friends` and `clients` tables have a `number` column that I want to compare in this query: IF `friends.number` is already in `clients`' table (`clients.number` column) then don't select that particular row anymore.
How is it possible to accomplish this in one query?

Example:

---

```
Table clients:
--------------------------
id  name  surname number

1   john  smith   55555
2   sam   wesker  12345
3   adam  Nye     48745
--------------------------

Table friends:

----------------------------------
id  name  surname number clientid

1   abcd  qwert   88888  2
2   dddd  asdfg   48745  2
3   ffff  zxcvb   77777  3
----------------------------------
```

The query should omit the second row in `friends` because its number is present in `clients`' table

Comment: I note that you're missing a comma at friendgender. And you have one more than necessary at clientsurname

Comment: True that. This is more of an example though

Comment: Maybe, but it's all we've got to go on ;-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DATETIME function. Can you tell us more about that?

Comment: @Strawberry Converts the first parameter to DATETIME format that SQL engine (sqlite in my case but same goes for MySQL) can compare to another DATETIME for example. In this particular query it is meant to select only those rows that are between the two "SOME_TEST_TIME" periods. The format of that string, in case of SQLite would be: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add :

```
AND friends.number NOT IN (SELECT clients.number FROM clients)
```

Comment: Yep. Quite elegant, too, in my opinion